# Set data in instantiated view controller

Tags: swift

I'm retrieving data from my database where I instantiate a view controller for each item I get which works.

```
let vc = self.sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BabyVC")
```

Now I want to access the view controller and set data but I'm lost. I thought, like in C#, that I'd do something like:

```
let vc = self.sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BabyVC") as! BabyViewController
vc.babyNameLabel.text = baby.name
```

But the label returns nil.

The internet says to use segues and delegates but isn't it possible in another way when I have the view controller as a variable?

**EDIT:**
The label was just for testing and didn't knew that setting a label was the problem. Instead of setting the label, I'm setting a struct. That worked.

Comment: Never never never directly access a view controller’s outlets from another view controller. They should be declared private to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

The label is `nil` until the VC loads set a string var inside the class and assign the value to it , then set the label's text in `viewDidLoad`from this string

```
let vc = self.sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BabyVC") as! BabyViewController
vc.lblText = "Name"
```

//

```
class BabyViewController:UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var babyNameLabel:UILabel!
  var lblText = ""
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.babyNameLabel.text = lblText 
 }
}
```

Comment: Arh thanks for leading me to the answer. I was just testing if it worked and didn't figured out that I couldn't set the label. It works with a struct.